# What keyword should come first in a product page's meta tags?

Tags: seo, keywords, dynamic, meta-tags

Working with ~100,000 products. Currently the way I'm using has the following priorites (most to least)

- Model information such as name and model number of a given product
- Product line's associated keywords
- The site's global keywords

Is this a good way to generate quality meta tags and content? Should globals be more prominent or is it best to prioritize what makes each page different?

Comment: Are you only asking about the meta keywords tag? Or do you want to know about the description tag as well?

Comment: Any suggestions that can be useful based on these dynamic values would be very useful. Trying to think of a way to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [meta tags have no influence on your page's ranking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/12/answering-more-popular-picks-meta-tags.html)s, but can be used in a page's listing in the search results, I would make sure the description tag is written like a sales piece. It can be the deciding factor for users when deciding which search result to click on.

[The keywords tag is obsolete](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) so I wouldn't worry about the order of the keywords in there.

Answer (score 3):

Meta Tags are so 'SEO 1.0', you need RDFa semantic markup - 'SEO 2.0'. If you check out the Good Relations schema there are case studies about how these work for big brands that have implemented RDFa.

http://purl.org/goodrelations/